# retain the font in every system

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qt-designer

In pyqt5 application, i have applied a font for the label using css in qtdesigner

```
font: 57 68px "IntelOne Display Medium";
border: None;
```

I build exe using pyinstaller and run in my windows machine it works fine, but when i run the same exe in different machine, the font is different, its not bold

my machine:

[image]

different machine:

[image]

how do i retain the fonts in all system?

Comment: Do all devices have that font installed?

Comment: @eyllanesc : No there are many font family in my application, which are not present in other system.

Comment: So there is the cause, you have to make your application have the fonts.

Comment: @eyllanesc : meaning? how do i make the the application to have the fonts? i should not use css? i should add fonts in the python scripts for every label in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure the fonts are available, so the solution is to load it using QFontDatabase.

For this to be available there are 2 options:

- Use --add-data:

```
├── fonts
└── main.py
```

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


DIR_APPLICATION = (
    Path(sys.executable).parent
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False)
    else Path(__file__).resolve().parent
)


def load_fonts_from_dir(directory):
    families = set()
    for fi in QDir(directory).entryInfoList(["*.ttf", "*.woff", "*.woff2"]):
        _id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fi.absoluteFilePath())
        families |= set(QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(_id))
    return families


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # LOAD FONTS
    font_dir = DIR_APPLICATION / "fonts"
    families = load_fonts_from_dir(os.fspath(font_dir))
    print(families)

    # FIXME

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Command:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "fonts/*:fonts" --onefile main.py
```

Note: In windows change `:` to `;`.

- Use qresource:

```
├── fonts
├── main.py
├── resource.qrc
└── resource_rc.py
```

resource.qrc

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>fonts/foo.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/bar.ttf</file>
        <file>fonts/baz.ttf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

```
pyrcc5 resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py
```

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import resource_rc


def load_fonts_from_dir(directory):
    families = set()
    for fi in QDir(directory).entryInfoList(["*.ttf", "*.woff", "*.woff2"]):
        _id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fi.absoluteFilePath())
        families |= set(QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(_id))
    return families


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # LOAD FONTS
    font_dir = ":/fonts"
    families = load_fonts_from_dir(os.fspath(font_dir))
    print(families)

    # FIXME

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```