# Font missing for PyQt5 compiled with Nuitka standalone

Tags: python, windows, fonts, pyqt5, nuitka

I'm using PyQt5 to create an App and Nuitka for distribution. Now I encounter a problem that my font is missing when I send the distribution to someone else.

```py
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('some text', self)
        self.btn.setFont(QFont('Lemon'))
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('./fonts/lemon-regular.ttf')
    app.exec()
```

I use `Lemon` font in my script which is located at `./fonts/lemon-regular.ttf`. This works well when I run `main.py` but fails after Nuitka converting it to exe. How can I include this font to my distrubution?

I use the following command for Nuitka

```bash
nuitka --follow-imports --enable-plugin=pyqt5 `
    --include-data-files="./fonts/lemon-regular-ttf"="./fonts/lemon-regular.ttf" `
    --disable-console  --standalone `
    main.py
```

I found `./fonts/lemon-regular.ttf` in my distribution folder but the exe doesn't show the font as expected.

Comment: Use [QFontDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for response. That helps me to use fonts that is not installed in system when I run my python code. But it still fails in distribution. I've updated the code, can you have a look?

Comment: @musicamante It's not working even if I change the relative path in `QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont` to absolute path. I don't know what to do next. Please help...

Comment: I don't know nuitka, but I suppose that the `standalone` flag is to bundle all files in a single binary, in this case the file is not a "physical" separate file, and you have to access it using the internal resource system. Check the documentation to understand how to transform relative paths to those suitable for the nuitka binary.

Comment: @musicamante no sir. `--onefile` flag is to make a single exe, and that doesn't work as well. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798454/retain-the-font-in-every-system) which uses pyinstaller.